# How do class declaration parameters work in python?

Tags: python, class, metaclass, pydantic, sqlmodel

Recently I came across [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) package. It combines `pydantic` and `sqlalchemy` features to work with database objects.
What I noticed in [documentation](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/create-db-and-table/#:%7E:text=We%20use%20the%20config%20table%3DTrue%20to%20tell%20SQLModel%20that%20this%20is%20a%20table%20model%2C%20it%20represents%20a%20table.) is that `table=True` parameter that you use to declare a model class:

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, create_engine


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

I could never understand what this kind of parameters is and how it works.
How is it called and how can you implement one by your own?
I have seen a `metaclass` keyword when declaring classes, but I thought there is a strict
list of available keywords. But it seems like it's quite configurable.

This question is not directly related to `SQLModel` but rather to general `python` features.

Any information or links on this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://martyalchin.com/2011/jan/20/class-level-keyword-arguments/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is based on the `__init_subclass__` method that you can define in a `class` used as a `metaclass`. Look at the following example:

```py
class MyMetaClass:
  def __init_subclass__(cls, foo=None):
    super().__init_subclass__()
    cls.foo = foo

class MyActualClass(MyMetaClass, foo='baz'):
  pass
  
instance = MyActualClass()
print(instance.foo)  # "baz"
```

You can find more details about this in the python official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Comment: Is is also passed to the metaclass' `__new__` and `__init__`  methods - not only to `__init_subclass__`.